# Getting Configurable Options to Show for Related Products

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, related-products

A the title suggests, I am trying to get configurable product options to show for products in the upsell and related products lists on the product view page.

So far, Google has come up empty handed so am turning to you, the Magento pro community, for assistance.

I don't have much of a list of things I have tried as I have no idea where to start. However, I have copied over the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml` file into my own theme, turned on the 'add to cart' buttons and played around a little.

Any help would be great! Please come through for me, people!

Comment: Hello @wildcard27 , You find the solution? Can you help me I have similar to do

Comment: I actually don't remember, this question is a little old now! But knowing what I know now, I would imagine you would have to create a new block that extends the upsell block(?). I haven't touched Magento for about a year now so I'm drawing a blank, sorry. Would love to see this community (using the term loosely) actually contribute